# Why do I get the following outputs with as.POSIXct?

Tags: r, posixct

Passing any date with the format below to as.POSIXct seems to work except with March 10th, which then gives me a NA. Does anyone see anything that I'm missing?

I've passed a large list of dates from February to May 2019 and all output a POSIXct class except when it's March 10th.

```
> as.POSIXct("03/9/2019 02:00:06",format="%m/%d/%Y %T")

[1] "2019-03-09 02:00:06 EST"

> as.POSIXct("03/10/2019 02:00:06",format="%m/%d/%Y %T")

[1] NA
```

I expected an output of "2019-03-10 02:00:06 EST" on the last line

Comment: March 10th was the start of daylight savings time, 2:00 to 3:00 AM did not exist.

Comment: That time didn't exist due to Daylight Savings Time. After 1:59:59 on 3/10/19 in the US, it immediately became 3:00:00.

Comment: Oh thank you. I even did a search for what happens on March 10th, but missed that [shrug].